# How to redirect a page to another?

Tags: pages, redirect, htaccess

On my website, I have following url structure:

```
example.com/test/
example.com/test/a-page
example.com/test/another-page
```

How can I redirect all of the URLS that contains **/test/** right after the domain name to **example.com/info/**

I understand I can do it using htaccess, but I cannot format the rule syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following at the top of your `.htaccess` file, *before* the existing WordPress directives:

```
RewriteRule ^test/ /info/ [R=302,L]
```

The pattern `^test/` matches all URLs that *start* `/test/`.

Note that the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* (first argument) does not start with a slash (when used in `.htaccess`).

If this is intended to be permanent then change the 302 to 301 - but only after you have tested that it works OK.